# What system color to use to highlight required fields in delphi/windows

Tags: windows, delphi, colors, vcl, required-field

**a bit background**

I am currently using the `clHighlight` color together with a `StyleServices.GetSystemColor` call to set the background color of controls that are:

- not focused
- have a NULL value (`field.IsNull=True`)
- and are about a required field (`field.required=True`)

Its not about how to do the highlighting itself, I figured that out already.

Currently I am using system color `clHighlight`, but this makes confuses my users as they think the entire contents of the field is selected (see screenshot).

But I also have style support implemented, so using a custom predefined color is not really what I am looking for. after googling a bit I found quite a list here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors?view=netframework-4.7.2 but I am unable to find what I am looking for.

Using RAD studio Rio 10.3.1 Enterprise.

**The actual question**

So - what system color should I use? (not really looking for subjective suggestions, but for a more or less "officially recommended" constant to use.)

**a screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Highlight is for something that's highlighted, i.e. selected. There is no official color that would reflect an area requiring attention. My suggestion would be to use some kind of overlay if it is required; a frame, a mark etc..

Comment: I've used a thin Red border on a 'Find' panel but only one or two controls would ever have that applied. I would not use that approach on a data entry form, a DevEx type of validation solution feels better..

Comment: There is no "official" colour for this. Some colour the background differently (a very light highlight) and add some kind of border. Others use a red border, but only on validation, i.e. not before. But it is not unusual to give the labels of such required fields a red asterisk. I have seen the latter in programs and on websites.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: There is no more or less system color constant defined for this specific purpose.

**Solution/workaround**:

Thanks all for the suggestions. I decided to go for the `clInfoBk` constant (background color for hint windows), this looks far less confusing. One could interpret the color as a "hint" for fields that need to be filled out.

And it looks like this, in the default color scheme:

[image]